# Managing URL, appending the path at the right required place

Tags: spring-mvc, url, servlets

Home page `http://localhost:9090/aaa/Home.html` has a `button` with `formaction="bbb/ccc.htm"`, clicking this button would execute a method that would return a view `ddd.jsp`.

Things are fine except the current view path as I need should be appended at `http://localhost:9090/aaa/ddd.jsp` but actually getting appended as `http://localhost:9090/aaa/bbb/ddd.jsp`. i.e `bbb/ccc` should have been removed from path before appending but onlt `ccc` being removed.

More notes:
I should not change `formaction="bbb/ccc.htm"`.
I am working with `SpringMVC` and using `XmlViewResolver` to resolve views.

Answer (score 0):

I got it the view path should be `../ddd.jsp`